# How can I get window.location.hash on server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to get `window.location.hash` on the server-side code alone?

```
http://mysite.com/#here
```

I want to get `here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use some AJAX to send it as it's not directly accessible from the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Not without Ajax, but if you can use the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) instead you could do this:

```
http://mysite.com/?here
```

... and "here" would then be accessible on the server side. From JavasSript you could access it using `window.location.search`.